# Alignment in golang

Tags: go, memory, alignment

I am implementing a network packet in golang. It was already implemented in C++.
The purpose is to make the golang implemented client communicate with C++ implemented server.

They will communicate by packet. The packet struct is:

```
type Packet struct {
    length   uint32
    nameLen  uint8
    data     []byte
} // in golang

struct Packet {
    uint32_t length;
    uint8_t  nameLen;
    byte     data[];
} // in C++
```

Their underlined structure is byte array. When receiving a message in byte array format. We need to translate it into Packet.

```
auto p = reinterpret_cast<Packet*>(buffer); // in c++
(buffer's alignment is manually set as 64)

p := (Packet)(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer)) // in golang
```

To make them communicate, their struct alignment should keep the same.

Here comes the question:
After printing out their alignment, I get this:

```
type Packet struct {
    length  uint32 // alignment 8
    nameLen uint8  // alignment 8
    data    []byte // alignment 8
}
struct Packet {
    uint32_t length;  // alignment 4
    uint8    nameLen; // alignment 4
    data     []byte;  // alignment 1
}
```

They will decode the message differently due to the alignment is different.

I can not change the C++ code.

**Q1: Is there any way to set struct fields alignment in golang?**

**Q2: Is there a better way to implement golang Packet to avoid alignment mismatch when casting buffer into packet?**

Comment: Q2: Very, very much yes. Unpack the fields individually using [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) rather than counting on unpacking the whole thing at once across different languages and architectures.

Comment: Q1: No. Q2: Yes: Do some programming instead of magic.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll unpack the fields one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Adrian and Volker's comment,

**Q1: No**

**Q2: Do some programming to unpack fields individually.**

In **encoding/binary** package, we have

```
func PutUVarint
```

It encodes a uint64 into buf and returns the number of bytes written.
Somehow this package dont have public function to encode uint32.
So I did something similar:

```
func PutUint32(b []byte, v uint32) {
    _ = b[3] // early check
    b[0] = byte(v)
    b[1] = byte(v >> 8)
    b[2] = byte(v >> 16)
    b[3] = byte(v >> 24)
} // assume it's littleEndian

// to store packet length into buffer.
PutUint32(buffer, pkt.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same as c/c++ in an unsafe manner.

Just use an oversized fixed width byte array.

With that said you need to do your own bounds check.

```
package main

import (
    "unsafe"
    "runtime"
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

type Packet struct {
    length  uint32     // alignment 4
    nameLen uint8      // alignment 1
    data    [2048]byte // alignment 1
}

func NewPacketFromBuffer(buffer []byte) *Packet {
    sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer))
    packet := (*Packet)(unsafe.Pointer(sh.Data))
    runtime.KeepAlive(buffer) // So the buffer will not be garbage collected
    return packet
}


func main () {
   buffer := []byte{9,0,0,0,4,'d','a','t','a'};
   p := NewPacketFromBuffer(buffer)
   fmt.Printf("length : %d, nameLen : %d, name: %s\n", p.length, 
    p.nameLen, p.data[0:p.nameLen] )
}
```